# Why Collection dont have and getAll method?

Tags: java, collections

I may I not search enought but I haven't find any answer.

[`[Collection]<T>`][1] have an `T get()` methode, an `void add(T t)` method, and an `void addAll(Collection<? extends T> c)` method.

Then why we dont have an `Collection<? extends T> getAll(Predicate<? extends T> p)` method?

I know taht it souldn't be hard to make a subclass who implements it. But I dont understand why it is not already their.

Late edit:

Here a concrete exemple for sceptical.

I have to code :

```
            wellsDisplayers = new ArrayList<DisplayWell>(Arrays.asList(displayerList.stream().filter(x->DisplayWell.class.isInstance(x)).toArray(DisplayWell[]::new)));
```

instead of :

```
wellsDisplayers = displayerList.getAll(x->DisplayWell.class.isInstance(x));
```

But you are right stream methode is really easy to use and understand, just like how java sould be.

Comment: The collection **IS** all the elements.  Where you put the result of `getAll()`, in another collection?

Comment: Yes, you return a Collection

Comment: They have: collection.stream().filter(predicate).collect(toList()). It's a bit more verbose, but it lets you do plenty of other things than just filtering, and it lets you choose which collection to create, too.

Comment: If you want another collection, make a `new Collection` then use `addAll()`.   Basically the operation already exists.

Comment: @markspace I dont want the same collection. I want a collection with the element respecting the predicate. Like if I iterate it and test all values in an if.

Comment: One should always be careful not to overestimate how useful other people will find a method: adding a new method to an interface has very high maintenance cost; and, personally, it's not a method that I've ever missed. If you find yourself requiring something like this regularly, write yourself a utility method.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok. To be honest I doesn't know taht we can do that. But getAll will be easier more clear and not hard to implement. You could also use stream to remplace an addAll()

Comment: I say that write it myself not an problem. But add, get, addAll... getAll seem pretty logic to me and sould have been add since the beginning that why I suspect that their is an important raison if it is not the case.

Comment: If you add a filter() method (which would be the proper name for such a method), then why not also map(), flatMap, which are just as useful? It would clutter the API, and the Java designers preferred leaving all collection transformation methods in Stream (which is lazy, and thus more efficient at combining operations), and all collection-mutating methods in the collection itself. But it's a matter of taste and consistency. They could have. Kotlin collections have a filter() method, for example.

Comment: Filter modify the curent collection instead of return a new one. You could also taht we can remplace get(T t) by filter(? != T t). But you give me a reponse. They do it for efficiency and lowering maintenance. Ok. (I still don't understand why no one give me reponse like this before and act like if my question is stupid by the way)

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstood the concept of a `Collection`. There is no `getAll()` method since you already have every element. Simply use the `stream().filter()` syntax and `collect` or `map` to do whatever e.g.

```
collection.stream().filter(x -> x..) // do stuff
```

Comment: I would have say Ok for java 7. But the add of removeIf look contradictory  with your vision of Collections.

Comment: @JulienMaret streams are Java 8, not 7. removeIf/add makes sense, to remove an object of a collection or get an object in a collection. getAll to get the collection you already have doesn't make sense. Would it just return 'this'? Or would you want it to return an array?

Comment: @JulienMaret Streams and Predicates are only available since Java 8. Think about a bucket with elements inside. Your `getAll` would mean to pass the bucket to the next person which you already can do. That is what I mean with the _concept of Collections_.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz Thats true, that kind of... (sorry I have to use a french expression, it fit too well) "passé le bébé" (give away the baby). On the otherside, correct me if i'm wrong but java is an high-level programming language and it pretend to be easy as possible to read and to understand quick. It will make a kind of alias for the user (redondant but clear). Any way, you are right, filter offer more possibilities ans so is more appropriatefor an "responsive" programing.

Comment: @dustytrash that waht I said. It wasn't here for java 7. The idear is not to have all the collection, but a subCollection with the elements who respect a condition. "get all positive elments", " get all pair element" , "get all element starting by a w". Because iterate all the collection everytime is kinda heavy (I doesn't know .stream.filter() in first place). And because It seem weird to me that it was not added, and as I know that their is probably a good raison for that, i ask the question to know this raison.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz can I ask you to copy you last message in an answer with may be a citation of  JBNizet so I can design an answer it will be more clear for erveryone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`Collection.removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-), although you'll need to negate the predicate logic. Alternately, you can use streams: `collection.stream().filter(p)`.

As for why there isn't a `getAll` to go along with the other methods, I don't see where the `Predicate` parameter is coming from, you're not getting "all" if you filter some out. The `addAll` method adds all the elements, so the analagous method `getAll` would get all the elements, which is just the collection itself, so it would be redundant.

Also, `Collection` doesn't even have a `get()` method in the first place. Maybe you're thinking of [`List.get(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)). I suppose you could have an "All" version like `getAll(int[])` that returns the elements at all the given indexes, but that doesn't seem very useful when `subList(int, int)` already exists.

Comment: Collection.removeIf is only available since java 8. But that can can be alternative yes, even if it mododify the Collection instead of creating a new one. In Someway You make my point, it is an exemple that it is not impossible to add new method in an existing class.